# Maximum PWM Frequency from a MCU

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, embedded

I am designing a high-frequency SMPS with custom MCU and gate driver controlling network. I am hoping to have a controlling network with no limitations in controlling frequency. If I use a timer/counter to create a PWM from a high power MCU like STM32h7 (480 MHz), what is the maximum frequency of PWM I can achieve for the gate drivers?

Comment: You will have limitations. And the frequency you can achieve depends hand in hand with the duty cycle and period you want. I think the MCU timers are the least of your problems, do check the data sheet if standard timers are suitable for you or can you use the high resolution timer.

Comment: I second Justme. If you manage to update the duty cycle once per microsecond, you could get away with a relatively low resolution such as perhaps 4-6 bit, and could reach over 10 MHz of PWM frequency. But consider, what would be a more realistic update rate for the duty cycle... This will dictate your necessary precision and hence PWM frequency.

Comment: If you want really high frequency, then IMO you would be better off with analog PWM (infinite precision regardless of frequency) or  small FPGA with delta sigma modulation.

Comment: So tldr: While you could probably run your timers at 480 MHz this doesn't solve your problem, which depends on many more boundary conditions -> VTC for lack of details

Comment: I agree with all the above. But for SMPS, you do not really need to worry about duty cycle because generally it is 50%. However, frequency does matter and if you can get 10 MHz which is way more than what is usually required. 

For microcontrollers, you can not go over the Nyquist frequency and close to it, you will get a lot of noise. From Experience, you usually get 1/16 clock frequency with a single timer

Comment: I would imagine it's faster than anything you'd want to run an SMPS at (a few MHz? 10s of MHz?). Surely frequency and PWM *resolution* would be the stronger concern?

Comment: I do believe that the frequency and the resolution are the main concern. However, for the SMPS requiring a PWM of a few 100s of KHZ, would the resolution be a problem?